# Add a custom field to a phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts

Am building an app that requires a custom contact field ('whitelist', if you were wondering) for every phone number.

However, I only found a way of saving custom data for each contact, with `Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID`, but not for each **phone number**. I tried using `Phone._id`, but I got a `java.nullpointerexception` error.

This is the code I have now:

```
try{ //phoneId = get Phone._ID from cursor
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();                           
  values.put(Data.DATA1, "yes");
  int state = getContentResolver().update(Phone.CONTENT_URI, values, Phone._ID + " = " 
              + phoneId + " AND " +  Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + MIMETYPE_WHITELIST_CONTACT+"'", null);
         if (state == 0) {
             values.put(Phone._ID, phoneId);
             values.put(Data.DATA1, "yes");
             values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE_WHITELIST_CONTACT);
                            getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
        }  
}catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(ChooseContactsActivity.this,  e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what needs to be changed so it can save a custom field for the phone number, not the contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I figured it out. Maybe there is a better solution, but this works for me:

```
    values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
    values.put(Data.DATA1, phoneId);
    values.put(Data.DATA2, "1");
    values.put(Data.DATA5, phoneNum);
    values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE_WHITELIST_CONTACT);
getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

When I query, I just have to add the phoneId to get the result I need:

```
getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, {Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2},
 Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId +  " AND "  + 
    Data.DATA1 + " = " + phoneId + " AND "  +
            Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + MIMETYPE_WHITELIST_CONTACT+"'", null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for Add custom label number.
This is working code in my app...

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

if (CustomLabelNo != null) {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, CustomLabelNo)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL, "mayurbhola_newCustomTest").build());
        }
```

description :
CustomLabelNo : any number which you want to add in your contact.
ops : this is ArrayList.

```
getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

[Ref Link for know about getContentResolver] : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
this code for Add contact......

you can add other type of number and display name as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how you do it if you want your custom label:

    Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, name);

    ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<>();                        
    ContentValues phonesRow = new ContentValues();

    phonesRow.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                                            phonesRow.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,number);
    phonesRow.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL,type);                              phonesRow.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
data.add(phonesRow);
```

Answer (score -1):

As the class Contact is deprecated and has been superseded by [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html), you 'd better try the new one. The newer APIs allow access multiple accounts and support aggregation of similar contacts.

For the new [Phone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html) class, it has defined three columns.

- String   NUMBER  DATA1
- int  TYPE    DATA2
- String   LABEL   DATA3

I think you can use the **Label** column of [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html)

Comment: A. The `LABEL` is for a user defined description of the number, if it fits none of the .data2 options. B. Am using the new API.  I imported ...commonDataKinds.phone.-1. Please read questions more carefully next time .