# Android: how to relate data to a Contact

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contacts

I am new to android programming, and I am looking for a way to add data to contacts. In particular, I want to add several strings to a contact to use in my applications. I think that the best approach would be to have a separate database table (using sqlite) to store these strings and have a way to join the contacts with this table, for example by means of an ID of the contacts included in the table. Is this the right approach? Can you give me a code example of how to do that? Are there other ways to realize this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has the ability to [attach to other databases](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) so that their tables can be used in one query. However, this would require that your app can actually access the contacts database file, which is *not* the case.

The only way to access contact data is through the Contacts Content Provider. It allows you to add your own data by adding rows with a user-defined MIME type to the [Data table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#DataBasics).

Comment: Can you provide an example? Do I need to define a custom mime type or there are other mimetypes available for a simple "string"?

Comment: For examples, see [Adding custom data to contacts in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053352/adding-custom-data-to-contacts-in-android) and [Add a custom field to a phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853799/add-a-custom-field-to-a-phone-number/7332858#7332858). For how to construct your own MIME types, see [RFC 4288](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4288).